# How can I get some buttons to align-left and some to align-right inside a DIV?

Tags: html, css

Here's one of the many things I tried:

```
<div class="block-footer">
    <div>
        <button class="align-left">xx</button>
        <button class="align-right">yy</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the button xx to go to the left and yy to the right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **float property** specifies whether or not a **box (an element) should float**.

**Note**: Absolutely positioned elements ignores the float property!

**left**    The element floats to the left.

**right**   The element floats the right.

```
.align-left{

    float: left;
}
.align-right{

    float: right;
}
```

And Your HTML File

```
<div>
    <button class="align-left">xx</button>
    <button class="align-right">yy</button>
</div>
```

or else if you want to use it directly with inline CSS.

```
<div>
    <button style="float: left;">xx</button>
    <button style="float: right;">yy</button>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I gave a proper description.

Answer (score 3):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ANC3H/1/

```
.align-left{

    float:left;
}
.align-right{

    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using floats:

```
.align-left{
    float: left;
}
.align-right{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use style="float:left" and "float:right"

```
.align-left
{
 float:left
}

.alight-right
{
 float:right
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<div class="block-footer" style="width:100%;float:left;">
   <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
      <button style="width:100%;float:left;" class="align-left">xx</button>
      <button style="width:100%;float:right;" class="align-right">yy</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS property `float`, try this:

```
.align-left{
    float:left;
}
.align-right{
    float:right;
}
```

jsFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pqbFr/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="block-footer">
    <div>
        <button style="float: left;">xx</button>
        <button style="float: right;">yy</button>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```